# How to add a table next to another one (not AFTER) in DOCX JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docx

Is there a way to add a table next to each other using Docx JS? I tried creating a parent table, that contains a table inside of each cell but didnt work.
I also tried using a Parragraph with the two tables as children, but didnt work either